# Access denied when running .exe with sql server job agent

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, console-application

I created a c# console app, and I'm trying to run it on a sql server job.

I set the Type to "Operating System", and the command text as:

```
"C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\JobsApp\JobsApp\obj\x86\Release\JobsApp.exe"
```

When I run the job, I get this:

> *Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'FeedLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.*

So I give SQLSERVERAGENT access to the dll, but now I'm getting this:

> *Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. The process could not be created for step 1 of job 0x3E702A92E3799D4995984DF6641604F2 (reason: Access is denied).  The step failed.*

I'm thoroughly confused. Is there a different file that's needs access as well? What am I doing wrong?

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and created the exe with Visual C# Express 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you! Add that as an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app is in the C:\Users\Admin folder (why????), and therefore would require someone either logged in as `Admin` or specifically granted access to that folder to be running it. It appears that (thankfully) `SQLSERVERAGENT` is not running with Admin rights.

Comment: In regard to your last statement, is this bad? http://serverfault.com/questions/460825/package-run-on-sql-server-job-agent-login-failed-for-user#460852 Changing it to Admin was the only way to get that working...

Comment: Allowing Admin access to *anything* other than the Admin user is bad. It defeats the whole purpose of restricting access rights by having an Admin account. Your app should not be in a folder with Admin rights (and you shouldn't be allowing anything else to run with Admin privileges). The app should be running somewhere with restricted rights - the most limited rights it absolutely has to have to function. Doing otherwise is like locking your front door with a burglar already inside the house. :-)  There are dozens of posts here about security and UAC; you might want to do some research. :-)